# Nothing is printing in multind

Tags: indexing

I am using the following codes to generate index entries,

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true,openany]{scrbook} % 
\usepackage{multind}
\makeindex{index}
\makeindex{notations}
\begin{document}

This is my first index entry\index{index}{first index} under index,  I am defining one more index \index{notations}{$\mathbb R$=Set of all Real numbers}.

\printindex{index}{Index}
\printindex{notations}{List of Notations}

\end{document}
```

The output is here,
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `multind` is not on TeXLive and has a `LaTeX 2.09` status, from 1991. I would not use this package.

Comment: I think, running `makeindex` after `(pdf)latex` is necessary for `multind` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `multind` package is available on CTAN but it's outdated, being a LaTeX 2.09 package, in my point of view, as it does not have been updated since 1991 (apparently)

The same features of `multind` can be obtained using Enrico Gregorio's (*egreg* here on TeX.SX!) `imakeidx`.

Use `\makeindex[name=foo,title={List of foo}]` for each separate index and `\index[foo]{Your index entry}` and `\printindex[foo]`.

The major change compared to `multind` is the usage of the first argument to be an optional one and the key-value-syntax for `\makeindex`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true,openany]{scrbook} % 
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\makeindex[name=index,title=Index]
\makeindex[name=notations,title={List of Notations}]
\begin{document}

This is my first index entry\index[index]{first index} under index,  I am defining one more index \index[notations]{$\mathbb R$=Set of all Real numbers}.

\printindex[index]%{Index}
\printindex[notations]%{List of Notations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the really neat thing about `imakeidx` is that if no optional argument is given, the generated `.idx` file has the same base as the `.tex` file.  it's beautiful in its simplicity.  (but of course, every `.idx` file *must* be processed by makeindex in order to get latexable output.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Of course, but with `write18` enabled, this is done automatically